# Tomcat terminal commands

Tags: tomcat

Is it possible to start/stop a specific application in Tomcat (7) using the command line?

This is to cater for when the manager app is not accessible via a browser...

Comment: Is the Manager webapp not accessible *at all*, or just via a browser? You'll need to be able to connect to it if you want to use it...

Comment: Yes, I can access it via wget/curl, but not using a browser.

Comment: @NubieJ: Please post the answer if you got it absolutely right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Tomcat manager can accept non-interactive commands. Read the section about supported commands: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Supported_Manager_Commands

If you want, you can also use Ant to issue some of those commands for you: there's a section about that, too.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz Perfect! That's exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Try this [command-line script for managing tomcat](https://github.com/kotfu/tomcat-manager) called tomcat-manager.  It talks via HTTP to the manager application that comes with tomcat, and allows you to do stuff from a Unix shell like:

```
$ tomcat-manager --user=admin --password=newenglandclamchowder \
> http://localhost:8080/manager/ stop /myapp
```

and:

```
$ tomcat-manager --user=admin --password=newenglandclamchowder \
> http://localhost:8080/manager start /myapp
```